# Are there anime named after a manga, but totally different from it?

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

Lots of manga get an anime adaption, and pretty often the anime's story deviates partly or a lot from the story told in the manga. This usually leads to different endings lacking information, or even giving surplus information as compared to the manga with the same name.

But this also made me wonder: is there also an anime that shares the same name as a manga (it supposedly was based on) but deviates 100% from this the story as told in the manga? So the story in the anime is totally different from the manga, but still shares the same name.

Comment: Define "100%". Do you mean they share a title, but not even characters, setting, or story?

Comment: @キルアPretty much yes.

Comment: Not a manga, but the visual novel [True Tears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Tears) apparently shares almost nothing with [its anime adaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Tears_%28anime%29) except for the name. Even the art styles are completely different.

Comment: Does True Tears share a similar "idea" though? Or does it entirely deviate from the original story?

Comment: @FatalSleep I haven't read the True Tears VN but the Wikipedia article indicates that the two works share almost nothing that couldn't be put down to being in the same genre. For instance, the main plot of the anime was a love triangle between the hero, a childhood friend, and an eccentric girl from his school who likes animals. The page on the VN says nothing about that kind of love triangle. The main heroines are a childhood friend and a girl who likes animals, but the circumstances seem to be totally different and their personalities sound nothing like the characters from the anime.

Comment: I thought of [Vandread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandread#Manga), but the anime seems to be broadcasted before the manga. Also, it still shares some characters, and background, although there are quite some differences as listed there. (Only watched the anime, haven't read the manga yet)

Comment: Yugi from YuGiOh was a master at all games, but the anime was only about playing duel monsters.

Comment: @krikara he did play Dungeon Dice Monsters and won against it's very creator and won Bakura's Shadow Game which had some very unfair rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, this is not manga, but I'd like to mention [*The Idolmaster*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster).

[The original game of The Idolmaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Idolmaster#Game_series) is an arcade game about producing girls as idols.

However, the first anime series [Idolmaster: Xenoglossia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idolmaster:_Xenoglossia) is a robot anime.
Girls ride big robots named "IDOL".

EDIT: Added some background of my understanding.

## Mushi Production

[Mushi Production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushi_Production) 
is one of first animation studios in Japan.
Mushi Production is known for [Tetsuwan Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astro_Boy_(1963_TV_series)) which is the first Japanese anime series.
Mushi Production was founded by [Osamu Tezuka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osamu_Tezuka) who is "Godfather of Anime" and the Japanese equivalent to Walt Disney.
This studio was created by manga/anime creators (animators).

At Mushi Production, animator's opinion was most important and business-side people didn't have a voice.

Lacking business sense, Mushi Production bankrupted in 70's.

## Sunrise

[Sunrise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunrise_(company)) is a spin-off company from Mushi Production.
The founders of Sunrise knew why Mushi Production failed, so they decided a new policy that have strong business executive members and animators can't poke to the business side.
For example, animators can't become board members of Sunrise.
At Sunrise, it moves in the opposite way: animator's opinion is NOT adopted.

Sunrise had a big success in robot anime.
For example: [Gundam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gundam), 
[Code Geass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Geass) 
and [My-HiME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-HiME).

## Namco

In 2007, Namco (the game company that created Idolmaster) finished acquiring Sunrise and merged executive members.
In that time, Idolmaster was one of the most successful games by Namco.
The executives gave an order to the animator team that created My-HiME to create an anime version of Idolmaster.
Animators at Sunrise were professionals of robot anime, they weren't fit to make idol anime, but they had a policy. Therefore, they created robot anime that used characters of Idolmaster.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure whether this pair fully conforms with your request but there is no doubt that these works share the same name but have nothing (not even the genre) connecting them.

You may have heard of [Kodomo no Jikan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodomo_no_Jikan), a somewhat controversial anime and manga. Well, AniDB reveals that there is another animation called [Kodomo no Jikan](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2001) — which happens to be a hentai with a completely different plot and different characters. (The link will probably lead to a 403 variant if you’re not logged in to AniDB.)

Granted, the hentai was first (2002) and it’s very possible that the mangaka just didn’t know it existed when she started the manga in 2005.